# Custom Debug Output in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

In the output window, there are sections called Build, Debug, and Refactor.

When I do `Trace.Write("Hello World!");`, it goes to the Debug section.

Can I create my own section like that and print data to it? I know there is a way to write a file but I just need to see the output temporarily in Visual Stutio.

I'm not sure if my question is clear or not, but is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only Visual Studio addins can create new output sources (those inside the output tool-window), like AnkhSVN does, and many others may also do.

I don't think you can do that from the code being debugged.

You can however try to create a custom listener and add it to `Debug.Listeners`.

You can make your own output form, with a text-box on it, and make a listener that outputs to that window, or something similar.